# How can I estimate the goodness of fit of a nonlinear model in Python?

Tags: python, goodness-of-fit, weibull-distribution

I have some data that I have fitted to a Weibull distribution and now I want to calculate the goodness of fit.

At first I tried using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test but I have read that this doesn't give a valid result when the parameters that I consider for the distribution are [obtained from the data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Test_with_estimated_parameters). Then I considered calculation the $R^2$ coefficient but then I also read that [this can't be used to asses the goodness of a nonlinear fit](http://blog.minitab.com/blog/adventures-in-statistics-2/why-is-there-no-r-squared-for-nonlinear-regression).

More or less those are the statistical tests that I know how to use and remember from my last course in statistics. Which test could I run in this case to assess the goodness of fit of the Weibull distribution to my data?

It would be even better if that test was already a well established [Python function.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html)

Answer (score 1):

Does [chi square](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) work for you? You sum the quotient of the square difference of expected and observed counts per bin divided by the expected counts per bin, and can find a reduced chi square using the number of bins and number of optimizable parameters (related to degrees of freedom, for which the input 'ddof' is modified in scipy syntax). A reduced chi square close to one generally means good fit.